# Load CSV sheet into Marklogic

Tags: sql

I need to upload a CSV sheet into Marklogic Database and perform some query operations on it. So, I had know whether a CSV sheet can be uploaded in the database and can we perform sql query operations on it? Also does Marklogic support CSV format? And which all query operations can be performed on it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to load CSV data.
Take a look at the 'mlcp' command.  Here is a 'recipe' for loading CSV using mlcp.

```
[http://mark.recipes/4/][1]
```

Another method is to convert your CSV to XML prior to injestion using one of the many available tools to convert CSV to XML.
An example is xmlsh:

[xmlsh csv2xml command](http://www.xmlsh.org/CommandCsv2xml)

If your CSV is consistant and simple enough it can be easily parsed into XML in XQuery or JavaScript in the server.   Depending on 'Which flavor' of CSV and how variable your data this can be from trivial to somewhat complex.

A 'trivial' example: given CSV that does not use quoted values or escapes, i.e. something like:

```
1,A Column,with,2.5,values
2,Another Column,with,2.5,but no values
```

a code fragment such as :

```
 let $names := ( "id", "description" , "value","comment" )
   for  $line in  tokenize( xdmp:filesystem-file("/tmp/myfile.csv"), "\n" )
       let $cols := tokenize($line,",")
       let $row := <row>{
          for $col at $pos in  $cols
        return 
          element { $names[$pos] } { $col } 
     }</row>
   return xdmp:document-insert( "/mycsvdata/row-" || $cols[1] || ".xml" , $row )
```